# Windows Phone 8 network traffic capture

Tags: windows-phone-8, network-traffic

Is there any way to trace network for downloaded store apps for Windows Phone 8?
I am not talking about emulator which cannot install store apps, I am asking for real device.

Comment: you mean like sniffing the data send by apps from your device?

Comment: Yes I want something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a proxy, I use Fiddler. Just run the proxy on your computer, connect the phone to the same wifi and set the proxy in it to point to your computer.

Comment: Will it able to capture network traffic other than http/s. like media streaming protocols such as rtsp etc?

Comment: If you use this approach, then all the traffic goes trough proxy